# Настройка "красивого" роутинга

Tags: .htaccess, чпу, mod-rewrite

День добрый, как сделать из такого url `http://site.ru/?section=news&act=statya-1` вот такой `http://site.ru/news/statya-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? /?section=$1&act=$2&dates=$3
```

Здесь я для примера добавил ещё третий параметр, `dates`.

В первой части описывается регулярное выражение, которое разбирает исходный URL. В моём примере это трёхкомпонентный путь, каждый элемент которого отделён с помощью дроби (slash, /) от последующего. Внутри части пути символ дроби встретиться не может `[^/]`, каждый элемент должен содержать минимум один символ (поэтому `+`).

Во второй части выражения используются переменные вида $N, где N указывает на номер выражения заключенного в скобках (backreference).

Подробности можно узнать здесь:

- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString (англ.)

Вообще весь процесс называется на английском *url beautification* и поиск по этому термину может дать много интересных примеров по теме.